# Can I change the default layout in Android Studio?

Tags: android, layout, android-studio

When I create a new project with a Blank Activity in Android Studio, it uses a RelativeLayout by default. I'd like to change that Blank Activity default to LinearLayout, rather than editing each activity - is that possible?

Comment: Change <RelativeLayout> to <LinearLayout>

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific - question is edited to say that I want to change the default behavior, not the results.

Answer (score 1):

I have already answered this question here: [How to change a default template files in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36654035/4786777).

Basically you need to look at the `recipe_fragment.xml.ftl` file, so you, know which files are used for the template.

The default template files are located in:

```
...\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities
```

So according to the recipe for the BlankActivity template, it says that it uses `../common/recipe_simple.xml.ftl` (if you dont't want to use a fragment layout) according to that recipe, it says that is uses this file to build the BlankActivity:

```
...\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities\common\root\res\layout\simple.xml.ftl
```

by simply replacing RelativeLayout with LinearLayout in your favourite text editor (move the file to the Desktop and edit it over there), you get what you want, but instead of that, I recommend you to make your own template, where you can define literally anything.

Comment: The path in this answer does not exist in AS 4.2.1 in 2021. I can get as far as `...\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\` but there is no `templates` folder in that path.