# How to set Relative Layout as default layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I usually use Relative layout for most of my activity. I want to make Android studio create Relative layout by default when I create new activity, instead of Constraint Layout. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: AFAIK, you pick the layout root element when you use File > New > Layout resource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default template layout files in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645161/how-to-change-default-template-layout-files-in-android-studio)

Comment: Usually I don't create a new layout, I copy, paste and modify an existing one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Right click on layout folder -> New -> Edit File Templates...
2. A dialog opened, go to "Other" tab.
3. Change the content of 
   "LayoutResourceFile.xml" and "LayoutResourceFile_vertical.xml"
   Change root tag to the type of layout you want. Hope this help :)

[image]

Comment: how do I change the value of the ROOT_TAG?

Comment: Maybe he means to say that we should replace `{ROOT_TAG}` with `RelativeLayout` but that is not the right way because if we do that, then if we create new layout, then in the new layout dialog, whatever root layout we specify, RelativeLayout will be put there. So the value of ROOT_TAG needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

goto 
'...\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities\common\root\res\layout\simple.xml'
and change default layout