# constraint-layout:1.0.2' Dependency Added Automattically in android studio 3.1.?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Why `Constraint layout` Added Automatically when I can't using the New Layout?

Following dependency is Added Automatically.

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Relative Layout as default layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678504/how-to-set-relative-layout-as-default-layout)

Answer (score 0):

In constraint layout editor on top there is icon (U shaped) for AutoConnect disable that

Check the below image

[image: Disable AutoConnect (U icon left side)]

Comment: The U shaped icon where to be Located?

Comment: I am not Using Contraints layout in my project. Then how to check?