# Want Relative Layout from the beginning

Tags: android, layout

Novice in Android Studio. Recently started practising basic coding. I want to have relative layout or linear layout from the beginning. Tried but could not make it possible. Could not find any option provided to select the layout theme. Automatically constraint layout getting launched. Please guide..

Comment: what do you do to get the ConstraintLayout? What do you mean by *beginning*?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678504/how-to-set-relative-layout-as-default-layout/38678614

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Relative Layout as default layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678504/how-to-set-relative-layout-as-default-layout)

Answer (score -2):

Change this line:

`<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
To

`<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

And do check your ending tag changes to this:

`</android.widget.RelativeLayout>`

Also (optionally) go ahead and delete this line if it's being shown in grey:

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

And also this is an optional change to make in project,

If the constraint layout is not needed in the project remove the following dependency from build.gradle by deleting this line and then doing gradle sync:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:......'
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: It's preferred to use `RelativeLayout` as a shorthand instead of `android.widget.RelativeLayout`.