# Is there anyway to use my android studio without this new constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

1. I learnt about Relative and LinearLayout, but now the newly upgraded android studio 2.3.. is automatically using this constraint Layout which i know absolutely nothing about.
2. Why does the constraint Layout choose automatically what i need in my own project? Is there any way to use my android studio without these constraint layout? which is by the way, very annoying!

Comment: just override the automatic generated xml which holds a constraintLayout with some other layout....

Answer (score 2):

1. ConstraintLayout is similar to RelativeLayout. ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy,
   Here is [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) for constraint Layout.
2. If you wish to change default layout. You can do that by editing default template file, which are located in:

> ...\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities

replace ConstraintLayout with RelativeLayout (or your favorite layout!) using any text editor.

for detailed information please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645161/how-to-change-default-template-layout-files-in-android-studio)